How to get all path parameters with their values
I am using net/http package in Go 1.22. As it natively supports path parameters, I was looking for a way to get all the key value pairs there are in the URL.
There is a method called PathValue, but that returns just one value at a time and you would have to guess what path parameter is there.

Directly, you can't. The relevant fields of *http.Request are not exported. You'd have to keep around the path pattern passed to Handle and parse it to extract the param identifiers, however it seems an uncommon use case. You use path parameters when you want to capture specific path segments which you know at the time of designing your API. Attempting to approach this dynamically might be a symptom of a fundamental defect in your API design.
